# Hide friends' page likes from newsfeed

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, news-feed

I like seeing when my friends like a picture or video. However, I'm tired of seeing pages that they like. I could care less about that stuff. Is there a way to hide just the page likes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Peek into the profile of that particular friend (even from within your News Feed, by hovering over the name of the friend, or by explicitly visiting his Wall)
- Hover over the `Friends` button
- If you wish, you can uncheck the "Show in News Feed" to hide all of his activity, or
- Choosing "Settings..." will bring you to the following submenu, where you can enable/disable the particular subcategories as you wish.
- In particular, `Comments and Likes` appear as a single, unified, choice.  Thus disabling "Likes" will also disable "Comments".

[image: Facebook submenu for choosing specific update-types for a given friend that will appear in your News Feed]

Comment: Repeat by x-number of friends you have on your account. Tedious.

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature has now been removed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Yosi Mor doesn't seem possible anymore. Instead, you can create a friend list, modify list settings to not show their comments and likes, and add the friends.

1. Click on **Friends**
2. Click on **+ Create List**, name the list something, and press **Create**
3. Click on **Manage List**, and under Updates to show, disable **Comments and likes**
4. Under On this list, add those friends.

Comment: Unfortunately, this option was removed recently. Although it appears that Comments and Likes do not show up in Friends Lists by default now.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook no longer gives a native way to hide your friends liked pages from showing up in your newsfeed. There is however a safe and free browser add-on called **FB Purity** that lets you filter out newsfeed posts based on the type of post it is.

One of its many available newsfeed filter options is one that filters out "**friend X liked page Y**" type posts. To turn that setting on, after adding FBP to your browser click the FBP link in the top nav bar at the top of any facebook page, which will open the FBP options screen, then in the left column, click the 
"Link / Page Stories" heading, then tick the "Liked Page" option, then click the "Save and Close" button.

You can get FB Purity here: http://fbpurity.com